# d3js: why doesn't first bar disappear using exit method?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a simple bar chart and trying to make it respond to user clicks. The clicked bar is supposed to disappear. All seems to be working except clicking on the first bar makes a bar at the end disappear. I'm completely at a loss to why this is the case and would really appreciate any help.

Complete Code on Plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/H8K0ISdhGrb5HirrX2MG?p=preview

I call the update function when a user clicks on a bar. I created a `removefromarray` function to return the data object minus data bound to the clicked bar. :

```
d3.tsv("CantTouchThis.tsv",function(d,i){
d.FieldGoals = +d.FieldGoals;
return d; 

}, function(error,data){
 if (error) throw error;
y.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){return d.FieldGoals})]);
x.domain(data.map(function(d){return d.Player}));data used as the x attribute

function update(indx){

var selection = g.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data.removefromarray(indx), function(d){console.log('d');console.log(d); return d}) //printing d shows the previous bars and new bars are being returned, I suspect this may be causing the problem, but not sure

selection.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class","bars")
    .attr("width",function(d){return x.bandwidth()})
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.Player)})
    .attr("height",function(d){return height - y(d.FieldGoals)})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.FieldGoals)})
    .on("click",function(d,i){update(i);});

console.log(selection.enter())

console.log(selection.exit())

selection.exit().remove()

}
```

Comment: You want the clicked bar to be removed or invisible? "Disappear" seems very vauge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1: You're missing an "update" selection:

```
selection.attr("width",function(d){return x.bandwidth()})
    .attr("x",function(d){return x(d.Player)})
    .attr("height",function(d){return height - y(d.FieldGoals)})
    .attr("y",function(d){return y(d.FieldGoals)})
    .on("click",function(d,i){update(i);});
```

Here is your updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/qJY5KgY9FBvuJ8krddYm?p=preview

Solution 2: another very simple solution (that correctly addresses your question, *"why doesn't first bar disappear using exit method?"*): use a proper key in the data binding selection:

```
var selection = g.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(data.removefromarray(indx), function(d){ return d.Player});
    //                    this is the proper key function ---^
```

However, have in mind that this "solution" will not work for all clicks. That happens because your method for removing the data object (using splice in an extended prototype) is **not** working correctly.

Here is another updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/rVTinxx45nmBvFiWwqgg?p=preview

PS: there are way easier ways to do what you want (and more adequate to a D3 code also).

Comment: Thanks! Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I want to clarify the problem with my code was that the first bar was stored in the update selection -which didn't exist - and therefore, couldn't be deleted

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. When we use an update selection, we assure that all bars will be re-positioned correctly. But forget that, try to focus on the second solution: when we correctly associate the data to the element, we can manipulate data knowing "what" element is going to change. But, as I said, you have a problem with your method to change the data according to the click.